# ClaimsPrincipalPermission and unit testing

Tags: .net, wif

I like using the ClaimsPrincipalPermission in my code, but there is a problem: The authorization code is interfering with unit tests.

How would you solve this problem? Off the top of my head I can think of three solutions:

- Have a separate configuration section for testing purposes that loads an authentication manager that always returns true to all CheckAccess calls
- Add a code snippet to the real authentication manager that always returns true to all CheckAccess calls when a unit test is running
- Create a custom authorization attribute that doesn't invoke authentication manager when in a unit test

Any other suggestions for a solution? If you implemented one of the above mentioned solutions I would love to see what you did.

Comment: Welcome! Can you mock it ? With for example  https://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart

Comment: What's the environment? WCF or ASP.NET ?

Comment: This time the environment is a windows client. And mocking is not possible (this is a standard Windows Identity Foundation approach where you do not control object creation by yourself), but the configuration section solution I mentioned above would essentially do the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom ClaimsAuthorizationManager that always returns true for the unit tests.

PrincipalPermissions in general are not very unit testing friendly.